How to Create a Rectangle in SwiftUI that Extends width According to the Number of Lines of Text within, swiftui (Similar to Wrap Content in uikit)
working on a SwiftUI project where I need a blue rectangle to adjust its ** width** based on the number of lines of text it contains, specifically not dynamically, but based on a fixed number of lines (e.g., 2 lines, 4 lines, etc.).
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // Background rectangle with corner radius - Top rectangle is here only for the shadow
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.green)
                .frame(width: 200 - 24, height: 20) // Width adjusted for padding
                .padding(12) // Use half of the padding to align properly
                .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 24, x: 0, y: 100) // Shadow for the top rectangle
                .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                .padding()
            
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .cornerRadius(20) // Apply corner radius
            
            // Text inside the blue rectangle
            Text("This is some text")
                .foregroundColor(.white) // Text color
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center) // Center align text
                .padding() // Padding inside the rectangle
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) // Allow text to occupy full space
        }
        .padding(20) // Padding for the ZStack
    }
}

!The rectangle should expand to accommodate the number of lines of text until it reaches the edge of the screen]1

How should the width of the rectangle be determined by the number of lines? Surely the number of lines will determine the height? Anyway, maybe you can just apply the rectangle as .background to the text, instead of using a ZStack?

I thought of that, but I'm wondering if there's another option, as I need a specific shadow effect as seen here

I was asking in a comment, how the width of the rectangle is supposed to be determined by the number of lines? I would expect, the number of lines will determine the height.
Anyway, maybe you can get the effect you want by applying the blue rectangle as .background to the Text, instead of using a ZStack.

This way, the background grows when the text grows, both horizontally and vertically.

If the rectangle should have a certain minimum size then set a .frame with minWidth and/or minHeight.

The rectangle for the shadow can use .alignment: .bottom, so that it is always at the bottom of the frame, even when the height grows.


Something like this:
struct ContentView: View {
    let theQuickBrownFox = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
    var body: some View {
        Text(theQuickBrownFox) // "This is some text"
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .padding()
            .frame(minWidth: 200, minHeight: 200)
            .background {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .fill(.blue)
            }
            .background(alignment: .bottom) {
                Color.blue
                    .frame(height: 20)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 12)
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)
                    .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 24, x: 0, y: 30)
            }
            .padding(20)
    }
}



In SwiftUI, the views are adaptive according to their content or their parent view. You can achieve your output like this:
 struct ContentView: View {
    let yourText = "Any text you want to display here.\nThis is a multiline text."
    var body: some View {
        Text(yourText) //Your desired text
            .foregroundStyle(.white) //Text color
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center) //Text alignment
            .padding() //Desired padding
            .background {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10) //Setting rounded rectangle with blue background
                    .fill(.blue)
            }
    }
}

In the above code, I have added a background that has the. RoundedRectangle component with the desired corner radius and filled it with the blue color.
